# how to decipher a Windows 8 dump

Tags: windows

I got a new Windows 8 PC 4 days ago.  Suddenly it rebooted.  The event log shows:

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000024 (0x000000b50019060b, 0xfffff8801d326748, 0xfffff8801d325f80, 0xfffff880019041e6). A dump was saved in: C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 040413-33828-01.

The file mentioned is over 2 GB.  There is also a smaller file in c:\windows\minidump

My goal is just to determine what program caused the crash.  How can I get that information from either the memory dump or the mindump?  Or is there a better way to figure that out?

Comment: Looks like a disk problem to me - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557433(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to follow the instructions here: http://www.networkworld.com/supp/2011/041811-windows-7-crashes.html and load the dump into windbg.  It points to a problem in ntfs.sys, which does sound like a disk problem.  Your link says to run a chkdsk, so I guess I will. Feels like the days of MSDOS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions here: the instructions here: networkworld.com/supp/2011/041811-windows-7-crashes.html work for Windows 8 to interpret dumps.  Thanks to roger_rowland for leading me straight to a page describing my particular problem.